# Issue retrieving ValueError: `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pre-trained-model

I have the following code took it from Github to run a pre-trained model mobilenet_v2 https://github.com/vvigilante/mobilenet_v2_keras/blob/master/mobilenet_v2_keras.py
and trying to run it, however, I am facing some issue to run the code. I tried to import it from Keras. applications.mobilentnetv2 but it didn't resolve the issue.

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import decode_predictions
#from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input

def relu6(x):
  return K.relu(x, max_value=6)
def _conv_block(inputs, filters, kernel, strides, use_bias=True):
  channel_axis = 1 if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
  if nlay < 0 or nlay > 16:
    basename = 'conv_%d' % (nlay + 1)
  else:
    basename = 'expanded_conv_%d_expand' % nlay
  x = Conv2D(filters, kernel, padding='same', strides=strides, name=basename, use_bias=use_bias) 
(inputs)
  x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, name=basename + '_batch_normalization')(x)
  return Activation(relu6, name=basename + '_activation')(x)
def _bottleneck(inputs, filters, kernel, t, s, r=False):
 global nlay
 channel_axis = 1 if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
 if t > 1:
    tchannel = K.int_shape(inputs)[channel_axis] * t
    x = _conv_block(inputs, tchannel, (1, 1), (1, 1), use_bias=False)
 else:
    x = inputs
 x = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel, strides=(s, s), depth_multiplier=1, padding='same',
                    name='expanded_conv_%d_depthwise' % nlay, use_bias=False)(x)
 x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, name='expanded_conv_%d_depthwise_batch_normalization' % nlay)(x)
 x = Activation(relu6, name='expanded_conv_%d_depthwise_activation' % nlay)(x)
 x = Conv2D(filters, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='expanded_conv_%d_project' % nlay, use_bias=False)(
    x)
 x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, name='expanded_conv_%d_project_batch_normalization' % nlay)(x)

 if r:
    x = add([x, inputs], name="expanded_conv_%d_add" % nlay)

 nlay += 1
 return x
def _inverted_residual_block(inputs, filters, kernel, t, strides, n):
  x = _bottleneck(inputs, filters, kernel, t, strides)
  for i in range(1, n):
    x = _bottleneck(x, filters, kernel, t, 1, True)
  return x
def roundup(n):
  x = (n + 6) // 8
  return x * 8
def MobileNetv2(input_shape, k, width_multiplier=1.0):
  global nlay
  nlay = -1
  inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
  x = _conv_block(inputs, roundup(int(32 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), use_bias=False)
  nlay += 1
  fix = 0
  if width_multiplier - 1.3 < 0.01:
    fix = -2
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(16 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), t=1, strides=1, n=1)
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(24 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), t=6, strides=2, n=2)
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(32 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), t=6, strides=2, n=3)
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(64 * width_multiplier) + fix), (3, 3), t=6, strides=2, 
  n=4)
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(96 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), t=6, strides=1, n=3)
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(160 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), t=6, strides=2, n=3)
  x = _inverted_residual_block(x, roundup(int(320 * width_multiplier)), (3, 3), t=6, strides=1, n=1)
  last_conv_size = max(1280, int(1280 * width_multiplier))
  x = _conv_block(x, last_conv_size, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), use_bias=False)
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Reshape((1, 1, last_conv_size))(x)
  x = Dropout(0.3, name='Dropout')(x)
  x = Conv2D(k, (1, 1), padding='same', name='logits', use_bias=True)(x)
  x = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(x)
  output = Reshape((k,), name='out')(x)
  model = Model(inputs, output)
  plot_model(model, to_file='MobileNetv2.png', show_shapes=True)
 return model
if __name__ == '__main__':
  model=MobileNetv2((224, 224, 3), 100)
  img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
  img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  x = preprocess_input(x)
  print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
  preds = model.predict(x)
  print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds))
```

Error

```
File "C:/Users/learn/PycharmProjects/mobilenet-v2.py", line 120, in <module>
   print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds))
File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 28, in wrapper
return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\keras\applications\imagenet_utils.py", line 14, in 
decode_predictions*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\keras_applications\imagenet_utils.py", line 222, in 
decode_predictions
'Found array with shape: ' + str(preds.shape))
ValueError: `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D 
array of shape (samples, 1000)). Found array with shape: (1, 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is meant to transform a vector of 1,000 probabilities into a category of the ImageNet dataset, which has 1,000 categories. Your final layer has 100 categories, so the function is confused. You could do this:

```
model=MobileNetv2((224, 224, 3), 1000)
```

If it makes sense according to your task. What are you trying to do with this function?

Comment: thanks for responding. With this function I am trying to understand the architecture for learning purpose.